# How do I change a Perl variable through a reference to it?

Tags: perl, reference

Why does this print `8`? Why doesn't `$e` alter `$i`?

```
my $i = 8;

sub u
{
    return \$i;
}

my $e = u();
$e = "eer";
print $i; #8
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

References are not aliases.  You must explicitly dereference them.

```
$$e = "eer"; # Store 'eer' into the variable referenced by $e
```

is not the same as

```
$e = 'eer'; # Store 'eer' into $e, discarding its previous content
```